# Suggest ambient/electronic/experimental music produced by female musicians

Tags: genre, electronic-music, similar-artists

I'm currently into contemporary electronic and ambient music - I love drone, experimental and psychedelic vibes.

I'm listening to latest Tim Hecker's [*"No Highs"*](https://timhecker.bandcamp.com/album/no-highs), and I enjoy Jon Hopkins [*"Music for psychedelic therapy"*](https://jonhopkins.bandcamp.com/album/music-for-psychedelic-therapy), James Holden [*"Imagine this is a high dimensional space of all possibilities"*](https://jamesholden.bandcamp.com/album/imagine-this-is-a-high-dimensional-space-of-all-possibilities), Alessandro Cortini [*"Volume massimo"*](https://cortini.bandcamp.com/album/volume-massimo), Bonobo [*"Fragments"*](https://bonobomusic.bandcamp.com/album/fragments), Tycho [*"Awake"*](https://tycho.bandcamp.com/album/awake), all [Nicolas Jaar](https://nicolasjaar.bandcamp.com/music) and [Darkside](https://darkside.bandcamp.com/music), and so on.

I noticed that all the artists I'm listening to are men, and that I don't know any female musicians/producers/bands that play this music genre.
I know I could dive & search for "ambient" tag into [Bandcamp](https://bandcamp.com/tag/ambient), [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/style/ambient), [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/genre/0JQ5IMCbQBLx5kZ4YrF0ki), ... but I literally come up with **hundreds** of names and I feel kinda lost.

So, here comes the question: can you suggest some contemporary female musician into ambient/electronic/experimental music, of the likes of the aforementioned men-musicians?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'll like [Alison](https://music.youtube.com/channel/UCGQ6yyoE94VNaQOXOhNOE7g) [Goldfrapp](https://music.youtube.com/channel/UCsl-0-9ybysnOXQsMvm_7Lw) (more palatable), [Delia Derbyshire](https://music.youtube.com/channel/UCb2lrb7wdT4nSlpa6J8lDIg) (more retro), [Tanya Tagaq](https://music.youtube.com/channel/UC51fA5zmbRw0Tdls-R8bpnA) (more experimental).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know Goldfrapp but she's too much on the dance/electro-pop side, I'm looking for a mor ambient/instrumental kind of sound. I didn't know of Tanya Tagaq: for what I've listened to I can say I love the music but I can't stand the _spoken word_ style on it. - but I will give her another chance, she's very interesting. Good spot for Delia Derbyshire!

Comment: Oh, Mute Records always releases the official instrumentals for Goldfrapp albums, I think only Felt Mountain doesn't have an official one. I think most of them are perfect for ambient music. I wish every recording studio would do this.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about that, thanks for pointing out. I'll go to check it out!